# Displaying output in SQLPlus

Tags: oracle

I will open my SQLPlus with CMD in windows. When I write a query it shows 157998 rows as result. I want see the all result in sqlpus window, but it is not showing all the result.

Comment: You're really going to read all 157998 rows?

Answer (score 3):

Not an Oracle/SQL*Plus problem. The default size of commandline window screen buffer is 300 (lines), and the maximum is 9999 (lines), so it is unable to display 157998 rows.

Better spool the output to a file:

```
SQL> spool output.txt
SQL> select ...
SQL> spool off
```

After that you can view the result in the file output.txt